# Reduced scope for Gmail IMAP access

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I want to access `Gmail` via `IMAP`, but for read-only purposes (using the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly`)

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol#oauth_20_scopes) the scope needed for `IMAP` access is `https://mail.google.com/` which is [defined](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes) as:

> Full access to the account, including permanent deletion of threads
>   and messages. This scope should only be requested if your application
>   needs to immediately and permanently delete threads and messages,
>   bypassing Trash; all other actions can be performed with less
>   permissive scopes.

but that scope is really a lot more then I need, and might prevent users from giving the app this permission.

Has anyone succeeded in getting `IMAP` access for read-only purpose? If not, can anyone shed some light on why full acccess is necessary? Is that a limitation of the `IMAP` protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The scope for IMAP and SMTP access is https://mail.google.com/.

IMO this is probably due to the nature of IMAP and SMTP servers.  By using IMAP and SMTP you are logging directly into the mail server.  I don't think you will get any other scope to work with that.

If you were using the Gmail API you are running though the API which gains its access from the Oauth authentication server. The authentication server will allow you to reduce the [scopes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes) needed.

Comment: thanks, that's what i assumed, wanted to make sure i wasn't missing anything